# How to extract text from a cell with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract text from a cell.

Ex)

I want to extract anything after from and before the letters/numbers:

> Zelle Payment from TopTipToe Salon WFCT0RJT7
> Zelle Payment from Pekoe LLC 183488888
> Zelle Payment from Nickola LLC 456806

It should look like this:

> TopTipToe Salon
> Pekoe LLC
> Nickola LLC

I tried `Mid` and `Find` functions.
It gave me "From TopTipToe Salon" but I need to remove the "From".

Comment: Are there always two words in the part you want to extract?

Comment: sometimes 3,4, 5. it depends on the company's name

Answer (score 3):

**Functions**:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1:A3," from ")," ",-1)
```

---

**Python in Excel**:

Just for fun, using [Python in Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/python-in-excel) through Anaconda:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
xl("A1:A3").replace(r'^.*\bfrom\s+(.+)\s+[A-Z\d]+$', r'\1', regex=True)
```

---

Here we are using pre-initialized Panda's [replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function to use a regular expression to find the substring of interest. This is captured in a 1st capture group which is referenced in the 2nd parameter as '\1', known as a backreference.

The pattern:

- `^` - Start-string anchor;
- `.*\bfrom\s+` - Match zero+ (`.*`) characters (other than newline), a word-boundary (`\b`), then literally match `from` and 1+ whitespace characters (`\s+`);
- `(.+)` - A 1st capture group to hold 1+ characters other than newline (`.+`);
- `\s+[A-Z\d]+` - 1+ Whitespace chars (`\s+`) before 1+ characters from given character class `[.....]` containing uppercase alpha and digits (`[A-Z]\d]+`);
- `$` - End-string anchor.

Comment: Nice solution using `Python`. Just tested worked perfectly Sir

Comment: thank you for the solution! do you happen to know the function equivalence to googlesheets? it works fine on excel but my coworker just told me that they also use googlesheets too and wants me to figure it out on there. I tried using before and after function on GS but it is giving me an error. Since GS doesnt have Before/After Text, it has left and right. I'm gonna look more into it

Comment: Also I noticed if I highlight and copy a payment and paste it with an extra space "Zelle Payment from TopTipToe Salon WFCT0RJT7 " it will not work properly. where would i add the trim function in this?

Comment: @TestingTesting `=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(TRIM(A1:A3)," from ")," ",-1)`. About GS, I suppose that app has a function called `REGEXREPLACE()`. I'm sure that's where the answer lays.

Comment: Informative & helpful; couldn't abstain to post another approach based on `FilterXML` :+)

Comment: Update @JvdV so the GS Function RegEXReplace does work but now I'm trying to figure out how to get rid of the words after the X company. 

Cell A1: Zelle Payment from TopTipToe Salon WFCT0RJT7

=REGEXREPLACE(F48,"Zelle payment from ",) Will show up as "TopTipToe Salon WFCT0RJT7" should I add another REGEXREPLACE? I tried adding it at the end and it doesnt work.

Comment: A wild guess: `=REGEXREPLACE(F48,"^.* from (.+) [A-Z\d]+\s*$","$1")` @TestingTesting

Comment: @JvdV Hello again, I tried it and it didn't work. gonna try again today and if it doesnt work. I'll give up on it since we have the MS Excel workbook. ALSO TY FOR THE HELP!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you need VBA, but try this function which returns the portion of the string starting at the word after `from`  and stripping of the last word

```
Option Explicit
Function Company(S As String) As String
    Dim sTemp As String

sTemp = Trim(S)
sTemp = Mid(sTemp, InStr(1, sTemp, "from") + 5)
Company = Mid(sTemp, 1, InStrRev(sTemp, " ") - 1)

End Function
```

You can also do this with worksheet functions as shown by @JvDv

Comment: Helpful & kept simple +:); might be interested in my split & join approach. @RonRosenfeld

Answer (score 1):

**Two flexible approaches**

Both solutions allow to get result strings containing 0, 1 or several inner word combinations.

**1) via `Split()`**

executing a simple split and join action

```
Function Xtract(ByVal s) As String
    Dim tmp
    tmp = Split(Split(Trim(s), "from")(1))                               ' get words to the right of "from"
    Xtract = Trim(Join(Filter(tmp, tmp(UBound(tmp)), Include:=False)))   ' join inner parts w/o last element
End Function
```

**2) via `FilterXML()`**

For the sake of the art another approach based on two `FilterXML` arguments

- a given string input translated into a wellform **xml** content and
- an **XPath expression** `"//w[not(following::*='from')][.!='from'][position()!=last()]"` defining three conditions to exclude the parts *around* the inner content:

```
Function XtractXML(s As String) As String
'a) define XPath expression
    Const xpath = "//w[not(following::*='from')][.!='from'][position()!=last()]"
'b) build wellformed xml content string from input s
    Dim xml As String
    xml = "<r><w>" & Replace(s, " ", "</w>" & vbNewLine & "<w>") & "</w></r>"
'c) return FilterXML result as string
    XtractXML = check(Application.FilterXML(xml, xpath))
End Function
```

*Help function `check()`*

```
Function check(XMLResult) As String
'Purp.: check different variable types & return string result
    Select Case VarType(XMLResult)
    Case vbError                                 ' no element at all
        check = ""
    Case Is < vbArray                            ' one element only
        check = XMLResult
    Case Else                                    ' several elements
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To UBound(XMLResult)
            check = XMLResult(1, 1) & " " & XMLResult(i, 1)
        Next
    End Select
End Function
```

**Recommended reading** *(listing a veritable wealth of `XPath` expressions)*

*@JvdV 's nearly encyclopaedic post* [Extract substrings from string using `FilterXML()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml/61837697#61837697)

**Alternative XPath**/*Edit as of 2023-09-09*

JvdV 's elegant alternative in comment suggests a slightly modified *XPath expression* which
searches for all subsequent `<w>..</w>` nodes (except the last one) that appear after the (last) occurrence of the search term "from":

```
Const xpath = "//w[.='from'][last()]//following::*[position()<last()]"
```

*or even without double slashes before `"/following::..."` (as in this example there is no need to distinguish between the highest or lower hierarchy levels)*

```
Const xpath = "//w[.='from'][last()]/following::*[position()<last()]"
```

Comment: Always a joy to see these answers around! Slightly different selector: `//w[.='from']//following::*[position()<last()]`. I suppose this would not hold up if there are more than one * 'from'. What does work though is `//w[.='from'][last()]//following::*[position()<last()]` where you'd select all nodes 'from' and then only keep the last one...

Answer (score 0):

The code is only tested for three samples.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim Arr, Itm
    Arr = Array("Zelle Payment from TopTipToe Salon WFCT0RJT7", _
        "Zelle Payment from Pekoe LLC 183488888", _
        "Zelle Payment from Nickola LLC 456806")
    For i = 0 To 2
        Itm = Split(Arr(i))
        Debug.Print Itm(3) & Chr(32) & Itm(4)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

Loading data from active worksheet.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim Arr, Itm
    With ActiveSheet
        Arr = .Range(.[a1], .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr)
        Itm = Split(Arr(i, 1))
        If UBound(Itm) > 4 Then
            Debug.Print Itm(3) & Chr(32) & Itm(4)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: would I have to input the new data in the VBA code everytime? Each day I get new Payments from different ppl.

Comment: Of course no. You can keep data in worksheet or csv. VBA will load data. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

If your strings all start with "Zelle payment from ", then your question becomes "how do I get everything between that and the 'last' item in the string".
The easiest way to do this is to "split" the string into non-blank parts, then reassemble the parts in the middle, excluding the last one.
So - you need to write a VBScript function in Excel

```
Function ZelleMiddleSplit(ByVal sIn As String) As String
Dim aParts() As String
Dim sOut As String
    sOut = ""
    aParts = Split(Trim(sIn), " ")    '   break everything into separate parts

    '   assemble the 4th part thru the next to last part
    For i = 3 To (UBound(aParts) - 1)
        sOut = sOut + " " + aParts(i)
    Next ' i
    
    '   return the result string - trim to remove the leading blank
    ZelleMiddleSplit = Trim(sOut)
    Exit Function
End Function
```

Some tricks to consider.
First - I always "trim()" all input strings, as often there are trailing blanks.
In your case, the first 3 "words" are always to be discarded, so my index starts at 3 (VBScript arrays are 0-indexed, and count from 0 to number of things - 1).  Ubound()-1 excludes the last part.
I always initialize an output string to "" rather than leaving it undefined - in many languages, undefined is NULL, which is not the same as a zero-length string.